# RedBeanPHP| Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense() must be an instance of RedBeanPHP\OODB, null given

Tags: php, база-данных, redbeanphp

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense() must be an instance of RedBeanPHP\OODB, null given

Вот такая ошибка в RedBeanPHP. Пытаюсь создать таблицу `users` в базе данных вот таким методом:

```
$data = $_POST;

$user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->login = $data['login'];
        $user->password = $data['password'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        R::store($user);
```

Уже и всё убирал, и добавлял, и базу данных сто раз переподключал. Кстати вот подключение

```
<?php
require 'rb.php';
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;
        dbname=baza','root','');
?>
```

В чём может быть проблема?(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо великие люди за помощь.

Я решил сам. Ошибка, насколько я понял указывает на проблемы с подключением файла `rb.php` и местоположением кода который подключает бд (методом исключения пробовал всё, пока не пришёл к такому выводу)

Решил проблему так:

в основной файл подключил `rb.php`

```
require_once 'rb.php';
```

Ранее было вообще по-другому, rb.php был подключен в database.php, а вот она уже подключалась к основному файлу, имея путь libs/database.php. Кароче полный фарш.

Ну и на последок переместил

```
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;
        dbname=yourname','root','');
```

Код подключения к бд в основной файл

Кстати нигде в интернете решения данной проблемы  не нашел :с