# Ошибка с redbeanphp

Tags: mysql, redbeanphp

```
if( empty($errors) )
{
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->login = $data['login'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = $data['password'];
    R::store($user);


} else
{
    echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
}
```

Подключение`<?php
require "libs/rb.php";
 R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost/;dbname=regbase',
        'mysql', 'mysql' ); //for both mysql or mariaDB
?>`

Выдает ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense() must be an instance of RedBeanPHP\OODB, null given, called in C:\Users\Chekhov\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\base.ru\libs\rb.php on line 10723 and defined in C:\Users\Chekhov\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\base.ru\libs\rb.php:12650 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Chekhov\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\base.ru\libs\rb.php(10723): RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense(NULL, 'users', 1, false) #1 C:\Users\Chekhov\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\base.ru\signup.php(29): RedBeanPHP\Facade::dispense('users') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Chekhov\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\base.ru\libs\rb.php on line 12650

Ранее ошибок не было, после добавления кода выше, стала появляться. Убрал в бд все подчеркивания, пробовал менять регистры, но не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вы не корректно указали путь к Вашей таблице.
Чтобы решить Вашу задачу необходимо:
 1. Проверить подключение к БД.
 2. Проверить название таблицы (необходимо соблюдать регистр букв)
 3. Проверить передаваемые данные (Хотя `RedBean` способен менять тип данных в соответствии с передаваемыми, но на всякий случай, для уверенности, что они не пустые)
 4. Убедиться, что нет других обязательных столбцов. 
 5. Проверить путь к подключаемому файлу.

Была подобная проблема у одного из пользователей данного сообщества [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931568/redbeanphp-catchable-fatal-error-argument-1-passed-to-redbeanphp-util-dispense)

Для уверенности вот рабочий пример (Файл `rb.php` находится в той же папке, что и сам файл):

```php
<?php
require_once "rb.php";
R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'login', 'password' );
if(!R::testConnection()) die('No DB connection!');
$errors = null;

$data = ['login' => '123', 'email' => '111', 'password' => '222'];

if( empty($errors) ) {
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->login = $data['login'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = $data['password'];
    R::store($user);
    print_r($user);
} else {
    echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
}
?>
```

Как выглядит БД и пример заполнения данных скриптом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)